# What are the differences between Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 for a headless VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, headless

I'm going to be spinning up several headless Ubuntu VMs in the coming weeks and need to decide which version I should use. I read up on the primary difference between 16 and 18 and found it mainly revolves around the UI. As my VMs will be purely command line, I was wondering what differences there would be for me as a developer for creating a 16.04 VM over a 18.04 VM and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't need older packages that 16.04 brings or some other quirks, you should use the latest stable version available.

1. It comes with newer software packages in the standard repositories. This affects maintenance and flexibility of the environments.
2. There's also a newer kernel.
3. The support time is longer - this applies to LTS versions (both 18.04 and 16.04 are LTS) - compare [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#Releases).

Some smaller bits and pieces may be modernised too. Stable (so also LTS) versions are well tested, and there's no point in sticking to older ones.

Comment: One critical difference would be how network is managed. Netplan ought to be more scriptable but the classic network management methods seem more robust to me

Comment: Thank you for the info, this was exactly what I was looking for. Good bye 16.04 :)